# merge two different tables in linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

i just tried to merge two different tables (Entity Framework) to a new one in the shortest and effective way:

Table 1:
GUID test
GUID rainbow

Table 2:
GUID test
GUID rainbow
string Alias

The new table should contains ALL rows from Table1 and ALL rows from Table2 - the missing column from Table 1(string Alias) should be empty on the new table if the row is from Table 1.

I tried it with union and with Intersect (only possible if both tables are equal). But i don`t succeed till now - any suggestions ?

Comment: A [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<Table1> src1=...;
IQueryable<Table2> src2=...;


var merged=src1.Select(x=>new {test=x.test, rainbow=x.rainbow, Alias=string.Empty}).Concat(src1.Select(x=>new {test=x.test, rainbow=x.rainbow, Alias=x.Alias}));
```